# How can I get close to non-nullable reference types in C# today?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, non-nullable

I've read many of the [non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=non-nullable) questions and answers.  It looks like the best way to get close to non-nullable types in C# (4.0) is Jon Skeet's [NonNullable<>](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/10/06/non-nullable-reference-types/) hack.

However, it seems that C++/CLI has solved much of the problem by supporting managed references: `Foo%` (instead of native C++ `Foo&`).  The compiler makes this work by adding `modreq(IsImplicitlyDereferenced)` to the argument.  Trying to call such a function from C# results in:

```
'<FunctionName>' is not supported by the language
```

Is there anything better then *NonNullable<>*?

Is there any way to (reasonably--i.e., w/o using reflection) call a C++/CLI method `Foo::Method(Bar%)` from C#?

---

**[edit]** It seems there is currently nothing better than *NonNullable<>*...I wish I would have gotten some comments on the C++/CLI stuff as it already has at least a partial solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've run into this a few times...I've yet to find anything better than Skeet's solution.  It's solved all the cases I've come across, so I have to give it my vote.

I agree it's a bit of a hacky situation that we have to resort to that...but his fix does solve the problem.

Comment: @Russell - He asked if there's a better solution...after a lot of searching I never found one.  If I was about to spend a lot of time looking, it's the answer I'd want from the start.  This was in response to part of his question: "Is there anything better then NonNullable<>?"

Answer (score 1):

Yep, spec#: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/

-- Edit: I just noticed you said C# 4.0; I'm fairly sure Spec# doesn't support that version. Nevertheless, it's worth a review.

You may also be able (I think) to check at a slightly later stage then compile, via a rule in Gendarme: http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme (assuming that runs against 4.0)