# Create a method or list that can't receive null arguments

Tags: c#, class, generics, compile-time, non-nullable

I have a `node` class that basically consists of a `parent` property and a list of childs.
There's an `AddChild` method which shouldn't receive null as an argument. Users shall not add a null child.

But the `parent` property must allow null values (a root node has a null parent).

The question is "How to forbid users to add null children at `compile-time`?". I know I could add a `NullArgumentException`, but that is not what I need.

Another way around would be creating a List that doesn't accept null items (compile-time).

Code:

```
class Node
{
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    private List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();

    public void AddChild<Maybe a generics solution?>(Node???? Child) where ????
    {
        //I don't want to add (if Child == null) Throw new ArgumentNullException();
        Children.Add(Child);
    } 
}
```

Comment: C# does not support this feature.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the fact that you don't want to have an if-condition inside your AddChild method checking if a null parameter has been passed?

Comment: Closely related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365459/create-non-nullable-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: I would read [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blog.coverity.com/2013/11/20/c-non-nullable-reference-types/#.UuK_ctgo7RY) about why there aren't non-nullable types in C#. It's not currently a feature of C# but a very interesting read.

Comment: Personally I don't see what's wrong with throwing an Exception. If somebody is calling `AddChild` and getting a bunch of exceptions, that will make them think twice about sending you a null `Node` in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

This is a "shortcoming" of C# language design. There is a way to make a value type (`struct T`) be nullable (`Nullable<T>`) but there is no way to specify a reference type argument should not be null. The best you can do is check for null and throw an `ArgumentNullException` (or use code contracts as pnewhook suggests).

See MailmanOdd's answer for a link to Eric Lippert's blog post on the topic.

Comment: That's a good idea, trying to invert things and make the node a struct, while `parent` would be `Nullable<Node>`...I'll think of the consequences....

Comment: @Daniel That won't work unfortunately. A struct is a value type, so you *can't* have one node "point to" another. You're on the right track using a class, but you'll have to live with the manual null check.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disallow null arguments, the best you can do is raise an error when an argument pre-condition is violated. Since you don't want to throw `ArgumentNullException` if child is null, I'd recommend [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Contract.Requires( x != null );
```

It's a little more terse and you get the added option of statically checking at build time if your precondition is violated.

Comment: Sorry....I don't understand what you mean by "statically checking at build time"...

Comment: With a little bit of tooling for Visual Studio, you can run a check as part of your build to see if any code calls a method in a way that violates a contract. It's 'static' in that the code isn't actually run, just evaluated.